# Php chatfunction. Scroll to the bottom of 'post area'

Tags: php, javascript, textarea, chat

I'm lost while making a simple php-based chatfunction.
My problem is the focus once a user enters the chat-page, since I added a scrollbar to the post window the focus is on top, while i want it to be at the bottom (to keep up with the latest posts). Any quick solutions?

Post code:

```
   <?php
   if (file_exists("mld.php")) {
   $file = fopen( "mld.php", "r" );
   echo fread( $file, filesize( "mld.php" ) );
   fclose( $file );
   }
   ?>
```

Write code:

```
  <?php
  if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {

    $com  = $_POST['txt'];
    If ($com === "") {
    echo "<font color=red><b>Please write something!</font></b>";
    die;
 }
    $time = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s");
    $com  = $_POST['txt'];
    $count = strlen($com);
    $com = stripslashes($com);
    $fp = $file = fopen( "mld.php", "a");
    fwrite($file, $time);
    fwrite($file, $com);
    fwrite($file, $count);
    fclose($fp);
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="";</script>';
  }
  ?>
```

js:

```
  function insertText(elemID, text)
  {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
    elem.innerHTML += text;
  }
```

It works as intended, beside the fact that the scrollbar is automaticly on the top once the page is loaded/reloaded. 
Any help with this code would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but if you're using a file to store the chat, you're going to run into problems if two people ever write to it at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use some javascript to scroll down it's pretty easy.

```
    function scrollbot(){
         var d = //select the element you want to scroll here.

                if(d.scrollHeight > d.clientHeight) {
                  d.scrollTop = d.scrollHeight - d.clientHeight;
                }
            }
```

Just run this function wherever you need to scroll in your code